# Shared object not found (libboost_python.so)

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I'm getting the error

```
libboost_python.so.1.45.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed libboost_python.so under ~/lib and it's symlinked to libboost_python.so.1.45.0 in the same directory.

I added the full path the to the lib/ directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH like so

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I then ran

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and restarted the server.

Any reasons why setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH did not solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It probably has something to do with the fact that `libboost_python.so.1.45.0` and `libboost-python.so` are not the same name. Note the underscore versus hyphen and the version number on the end.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. Fixed.